# Php OOP Bank Account Deposit Using $_POST

Tags: php, oop, post, bank

I'm having trouble trying to update the balance with my deposit function.  Basically, I'm trying to update the value of my $balance variable everytime I submit an amount to deposit in a form in html.  Problem is, it only seems like Its only updating what the next value is rather than adding into the balance.

I've tried this directly(not using the form) by adding values as parameters and invoking the method multiple times and it incremented the value of my total balance.   My only problem is trying to do that using form $_Post to pass in whatever is typed as a parameter.

```
 <?php

class BankAccount{

    private $balance = 0;
    private $name='Bob';
    private $date;

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name; 
    }

    public function getDate(){
        $this->date = date("m.d.y");
            return $this->date; 
    }

    public function getBalance(){
        if(($this->balance) > 0){
            return $this -> balance;

        } else if(($this->balance) <= 0 ){
            return 'Balance is empty '; 
        }else{
            return 'error'; 
        }   
    }
        public function Deposit($amount){

        $this->balance = $this->balance + $amount;  
    }


    public function Withdraw($amount){

        if(($this->balance) < $amount){
            echo 'Not enough funds to withdraw. ';

        } else{
            $this->balance = $this->balance - $amount;  
        }
    }   
}
    $money=0;
    if(isset($_POST['deposit'])){ $money = $_POST['deposit'];}

    //Instance of class
    $bank = new BankAccount;

    //Get Balance 
    //echo $bank ->getBalance();

    //Deposit
    $bank ->Deposit(50);
    $bank ->Deposit(50);
    $bank ->Deposit($money);

    //Withdraw
    //$bank ->Withdraw(30);


?>

<html>
<body>
<form name="Bank" method="POST" style="margin-top:25px;">

<label style="color:red;">Name: </label><?php echo $bank ->getName();   ?><br>
<label style="color:red;">Date: </label><?php echo $bank ->getDate();   ?><br>
<label style="color:red;">Balance: </label><?php echo $bank->getBalance(); ?><br>

    <label>Deposit</label>
        <input type="text" name="deposit" maxlength="25"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" ><br> 


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing the current value out to anything, such as a database or flat file.  You need to store and retrieve the value.  Try looking into $_SESSION and storing the bank account value that way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add inline style.

Use css external style in head tag.

When you use inline styles on html forms, it won't submit. Sometimes using entype="multiparty/form-data" works or using some jQuery script works.

But, I'll advice you don't add inline styles in forms.